# Selenium - WebDriverWait until any xpath saved in a list is found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I have multiple xpaths for one element, all saved in a list. I wrote my own wait function, but I would like to leverage the original one if possible.

The idea is to wait 15 seconds OR until ANY of the xpaths in a list are found.

I found this example of using multiple xpaths:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//example_xpath") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//example_xpath"))
```

However, my xpaths are in a list and the size is not known beforehand:

```
xpath_list = ["//div[@id='test']", "//div[@id='test2']"]
```

I can't grasp how I would write this at all.

Comment: How can be there an xpath which you don't know beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.xpath,"//div[@id='test' or @id='test2']"))
```

Why can't you just use xpath 'or' and EC.precence_of_all_elements_located

Comment: He uses a dynamic list to store a vairable amounts of xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a "true" to trigger your Wait to pass. So something like this may work

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver:
    passWait = false
    for xpath in xpath_list:
        if (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))):
            passWait = true
            break
    passWait


)
```

Sorry, quick answer, may have typos.